# How do I add a jumping delay to unity 2D character controllers?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is my character controller code.

```
    public float speed;
float Velocity;
public float jump;

void Update () 
{

    Velocity = 0;

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) 
    {
        Velocity = -speed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) 
    {
        Velocity = speed;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKey("space") || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x, 
jump);
        }

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (moveVelocity, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> 
().velocity.y);

    }
}
```

This is a very simple movement code
here is my cam follow code i got from Brackeys
I am having an infinte jump problem with the code and i do not know what to do to fix it
I do not know the correct syntax yet to stop it.
I am using Unity 2019.4.2f1 and VScode 2020.
Im not sure if adding what versions I use will help
but I am always getting compiler errors saying that stuff does not exist in the current context but i do not know anything else that does exist in the current context that will work.

```
    void Update()
{
    transform.position = playerPos.position + offset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix infinite jump, use `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)` instead of `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)`. The GetKey function is for checking when a key is held down. the GetKeyDown function is for getting the first time the key is pressed.